# Can i call method of other Activity from another Activity?

Tags: java, android, methods

I want to call method of Other activity. I searched alot and tried by myself but failed. It work when i call from class to class like classA m=new classA();
m.function();
But i want to call from another activity method. Please help

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    ChatActivity ch=new ChatActivity();
    ch.location();
}
```

Comment: Activities are just classes, if you have instances of the other Activity, you can call a method on it. What is your code, what are you actually trying to do and *why*?

Comment: When i call a method of class it work but failed when i call activity method

Comment: show the code!!

Comment: public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
ChatActivity ch=new ChatActivity();
ch.location();

    }

Comment: `new ...Activity()` is a very bad idea.

Comment: so? how should i call?

Comment: I only have to call it from other activity. when i run this app crashes. when i call from the class it works fine

Comment: show proper code and error

Comment: you could, but I don't think you should

Comment: Why did you place that code in another activity? If you need some common functionality, move it to a helper class or a common parent class. If you need the state of another activity, save the relevant information to the context when the state changed. It is a very bad idea to call from one activity to another.

Comment: @gaborsch the method is also running in another activity so that why i want to let the method in that activity and call it from another activity. i hope you got that

Comment: @MsbSays IMHO it would be better to move it to a separate lib class

Comment: You have resolved your ApplicationContext.getInstance() error?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ApplicationContext extends Application {

    public ActivityMain activityMain;

    public void setActivityMain(ActivityMain activityMain) {
        this.activityMain = activityMain;
    }

    public ActivityMain getActivityMain() {
        return activityMain;
    }
```

In ActivityMain.class

```
public class ActivityMain extends BaseProject implements MainView {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ApplicationContext.getInstance().setActivityMain(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ApplicationContext.getInstance().setActivityMain(null);
    }
```

Use it anywhere like Activity, Fragments, Broadcast Receiver or Service like

```
if (ApplicationContext.getInstance().getActivityMain()!=null){
ApplicationContext.getInstance().getActivityMain().callAnyMethod();
}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: You need to explain your answer a bit more :/

Comment: I guess this code is self explanatory...and required no explanation. I would like to upvote it.

Comment: This is good suggestion. If some one has better alternate I would love to know.

Comment: getting error of getInstance(). can you explain a bit more

Comment: Hey dude, you have an application class in hour class , if you don't have then create one, getinstance() is a method in applicationcontext class method which give its instance. You have to create get instance method in application class.